# Application of Ruzsa's covering lemma to iterated sum sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, additive-combinatorics

> **Lemma 2.14 (Ruzsa's covering lemma)** *For any additive sets $A,B$ with common ambient group $Z$, there exists an addtitive set
> $X_+\subseteq B$ with $$B\subseteq A-A+X_+;\quad |X_+|\leq
>  \dfrac{|A+B|}{|A|}; \quad |A+X_+|=|A||X_+|$$ and similiarly there
> exists an additive set $X_-\subseteq B$ with $$B\subseteq
>  A-A+X_-;\quad |X_-|\leq \dfrac{|A-B|}{|A|}; \quad |A-X_-|=|A||X_-|$$*
> Covering lemmas such as the one above are convenient for a number of
> reasons. Firstly, they allow for easy computation of iterated sum
> sets. For instance, if one knows that $$A+B\subseteq A+X$$ the one can
> immediately deduce that $$A+nB\subseteq A+nX \ \ \text{for} \ \ n\geq
>  0.$$

This is an excerpt from Tao-Vu book and I was trying to apply Ruzsa's covering lemma in order to prove that if $A+B\subseteq A+X$, then $A+nB\subseteq A+nX$. However, I failed to do that.

Can anyone show the proof please? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Ruzsa's covering lemma for this, just repeatedly apply the hypothesis.

More explicitly, by induction on $n$ - $A+(n+1)B = (A+nB)+B\subseteq A+nX+B=A+B+nX\subseteq A+X+nX=A+(n+1)X$.

Comment: Indeed, it follows easily from induction. I did not think in that direction. I initially thought that it somehow related with Ruzsa's covering lemma because this is what the wording says.

Comment: The wording is potentially confusing, yes. What the authors meant is that this is an example of what one might do next with the -conclusion- of Ruzsa's covering lemma (in this case, coupling it with an easy induction argument), not how the lemma itself might be applied.

Comment: Hi, Professor Bloom! I was wondering can you take a look at my question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4381533/green-ruzsa-covering-lemma